# Why doesn't the code after "await" in this JavaScript ES6 example get run?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I have the following snippet:

```
let zxcv = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(4)
    }, 1000)
})

async function jk(){
    await zxcv()
    console.log(6)
}

jk()
```

When I run this snippet, it waits for a second, then logs "4", then ends. "6" never gets logged.

Why?

Comment: The promise didn't resolve or reject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never resolved your promise in `zxcv`:

```js
let zxcv = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(4)
        resolve()
    }, 1000)
})
```

Otherwise the promise will hang indefinitely!